# How many threads does my machine really have?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, compilation

I have a Mac Pro with 12 cores and 24 threads (2.7 GHz 12-Core Intel Xeon E5), but when I go into the terminal and type the "top" command, it says there are 1621 threads. How can this even be possible? Is the word "thread" being used differently by top? I thought there were only 24. It seems there are far more because, aside from what I've said about top, I can compile with several dozen threads. When I type "make -j60", for example, the computer has no issue with launching 60 different compile processes, each working independently, compiling its own object file (or at least that's how it appears).

Thanks in advance,
-AA

Comment: threads in CPU description means how many threads can really run at the same time, top shows you total number of threads in OS, some of them are waiting to be executed by CPU, OS has special scheduler which orchestrates which 24 threads from 1621 are actually running every moment and switches between them from time to time, this is why all threads are progressing

Comment: in addition to previous comment, these two concepts are called ["simultaneous multithreading"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) and ["temporal multithreading"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_multithreading).

Comment: I see. So my machine runs 2 threads for each of the 12 cores "simultaneously", but is switching back and forth amongst the 1621 active threads "temporally".

Answer (score 0):

The CPU can execute 24 threads at the same time, two in each of its 12 cores. There are currently 1,621 threads created by the software on your system. The vast majority of them currently have nothing to do. As those threads become ready to run, the system's scheduler will cause some of them to be executed, subject to the 24 at a time maximum the CPU is capable of.